# A PGF node with a user-defined shape renders as a long, thin, and empty PDF file

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript featuring a PGF picture of a node whose shape is the user-defined shape, `myshape`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{shapes}
\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{
        \savedanchor\mytext{\pgfpointorigin}
        \anchor{text}{\mytext}
    }
    \begin{pgfpicture}
        \pgfnode{myshape}{text}{Hello world}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}
    \end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF file is long, thin, and empty.

I expect the PDF to comprise of a single, normally sized page that contains the text 'Hello world'.

Comment: Read the list at beginning of Section 101.5.1. When it comes to manual language you are criticizing but when it comes to coding you are not following it.

Comment: @percusse: I've revised the code to your liking, but the problem persists.

Comment: Use article class and you'll see the problem. Again you are not following the requirements. Even coordinate has text computations with zero size.

Comment: @percusse: I have to disagree with you that I am not following the requirements. Do you have any idea why the code works with the document class `article`, but not with `standalone`?

Comment: What is a 'single, normally sized page' when using `standalone` with default settings? Your picture has dimensions of zero.

Comment: @cfr: Why does it have dimensions of zero? Doesn't the text box count? By the way, if I change the node's shape to the built-in type `coordinate`, the resulting PDF is empty, even when the document class is `article`. Why is that?

Comment: You haven't given it any dimensions. The TeX box has dimensions, but you're not used them in defining your shape. Put an `\fbox` around the picture if you don't believe me.

Comment: @cfr: I believe you. I'm just perplexed. I don't understand why my manuscript displays 'Hello world' when the document class is `article`, but generates a strangely shaped empty document when the document class is `standalone`. Regarding your last comment: (a) I thought that `text` was a default anchor that all shapes had, (b )I get the same result, namely an empty document, even when I change the anchor to `center` (when the node's shape is `coordinate`).

Comment: @EvanAad The definition of `coordinate` does `\nodeparts{}`, which overrides the default `\nodeparts{text}`. So it does have a `text` anchor. It just isn't used to typeset the label text.

Comment: @EvanAad What is `standalone` supposed to do? It tries to crop to the relevant size. In this case, the relevant size is zero by zero. What do you expect? In `article`, the page dimensions are independent of the size of the picture, so you get a sensible-ish result, even though the picture has dimensions of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `standalone` truncates everything that does not report a bounding box. A bounding box by pgfpicture is tracked if its content reports anything that has size. Your shape has no size. Hence all is truncated and the strange looking page size is a standalone artifact.

In the article case if you keep typing regular text after your picture TeX will also overwrite since there is nothing from its perspective.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{shapes}
\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{
        \savedanchor\mytext{\pgfpointorigin}
        \anchor{text}{\mytext}
    }
    \begin{pgfpicture}
        \pgfnode{myshape}{text}{Hello world}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}
    \end{pgfpicture}{\Large\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Some more text}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Again, from the manual, about `text` anchor, before the deferred anchor which you have asked previously.

> [...]For the text node part we must set up a text anchor.
>   This anchor is used upon creation of a node to determine the lower left corner of the text label
>   (within the private coordinate system of the shape). By default, the text anchor is at the origin, but you may change this[...]

Comment: Thanks. You've answer my question fully, but could you please also address the issue that came up in the comments between cfr and myself, namely, why is it that, if you change the document class to `article`, delete the `myshape` declaration, substitute `coordinate` for `myshape` and `center` for `text`, you get an empty PDF file rather than a PDF with 'Hello world'?

Comment: @EvanAad `coordinate` does not have any text. As mentioned, if `\nodeparts` are not defined boxes are not typeset. Making new shapes are pretty cumbersome.

Comment: I see. One last question, please: why is the size of the node in the example given in my original post zero? Why doesn't the 'Hello world' box count?

Comment: @EvanAad Since text is thrown out and you don't have any extra background path computation the bounding box is zero. Hence TeX sees nothing but text is typeset regardless.